# How much loan you owed after 20 years

Tags: calculus, solution-verification, finance

Statement: Paying down a mortgage: you took a $\$200000$ home mortgage at an annual interest rate of 3%.suppose that the loan is amortized over a period of 30 years and let P(t) denote the amount of money(in thousands of dollars) that you owe on the loan after t years.A reasonable estimate of the rate of change of P is given by $ P'(t)=-4.1107e^{0.03t} $. What is the amount of money owed on the loan after 20 years?

I tried to solve it

$$ \frac{dP}{dt}=-4.1107\cdot e^{0.03t} $$

$$ dP=-4.1107\cdot e^{0.03t}dt $$

$$ \int dP=\int-4.1107\cdot e^{0.03t}dt $$

$$ P=-\frac{4.1107}{.03}\cdot e^{0.03t}+c $$

$$ P=-137.023333\cdot e^{0.03t}+c $$
$$ at~ t=0 ~P=200$$

$$ 200=-137.023333+c $$

$$ c=337.023333 $$

$$ P=-137.023333\cdot e^{0.03t}+337.023333 $$
$$ at~ t=20 $$

$$ P=-137.023333e^{.6}+337.023333 $$

$$ P_{20}\approx 87.35054 \cdot1000 $$

So answer is approximately 87350.54.Am i doing anything wrong ?

Comment: In real life, mortgages are not continuously compounded.  Using continuous compounding math may result something different from the bank calculates.

Comment: i wrote exact statement and i am also confused related to this question.can you explain what approach you will take solving this question ?

Comment: What is the context? Did you get the $P'(t)$ formula as a given from a math problem?

Comment: @gst076923 yes it is written in problem statement

Comment: @mathlearner Yes, it looks right.